# IBM identity and access management (IAM) : how to get user's token by sending user's credentials to IAM REST api?

Tags: authentication, oauth, ibm-cloud, openid, openid-connect

Here are the procedures for authentication that I would like to realize:
1. The user (a real person) sends his id and password of IBM Cloud to my application.
2. My application obtains the user's id and password, then sends the id and password to a REST api of IBM identity and access management (IAM) for authentication. If authenticated, a bearer token is returned in the response.
3. The user's basic information is contained in the token.
Is there such an IAM API I can use? Is this what happens when we login into https://console.bluemix.net/ ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can find many (but not all yet) of the [API docs for IBM Cloud on this page](https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/). In the security section you find the [IBM Cloud IAM Token Services API](https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/iam-identity-token-api). That is the simple part.

There is no such thing as a typical IBM Cloud user with a username and password. [IBM uses the IBMid for the public cloud and regular users. However, many users utilize a Federated ID, basically single sign on from their company](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/account/adminpublic.html#signing-up-for-ibm-cloud). To add to that, there are also [serviceIDs which can be used to provision and organize resources and to manage resource access](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/account/account_overview.html#overview).

Once you have an [API key or a bearer token you can access resources for that user ID or service ID](https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/iam-identity-token-api#create-an-iam-access-token-for-a-user-or-service-i).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In [create an API key](https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/iam-identity-token-api#create-an-apikey), it seems that the API key for a user can be gotten by sending a request only containing this user's IAMid? Without his password?

Comment: See the authentication section. The request needs to authenticate via bearer token.